# How to use Application instance multiple times or use simlutaneously?

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I have app instance in my service (onstart)

I have declared it as static.

public static Interop.Excel.Application app;

```
service onstart() 
{
app = new Application();
}
```

In my API code -

book is workbook object.

```
book = WinService.app.Workbooks.Open("C:\GetData.xlsm");
```

Now, I want to use app object in my multiple calls. It is working only for sequential calls. If I try to call the service from two users - it is not working. One by one is working fine.

Comment: probably the excel api is not thread safe, so you might need to sync access with `lock`, `SynchronizationAttribute` or another synchronization method

Comment: I do not want to add a lock. I want make it usable to all calls. Any suggestions?